# jQM selectmenu data-native-menu="false" running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm running the following jQM 1.3.x/1.4.x selectmenu with `data-native-menu="false"`

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="selectbox">Basic:</label>
        <select name="selectbox" id="selectbox" data-native-menu="false">
            <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
            <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
            <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
            <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and triggering the following event

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $("#page").on("change", "#selectbox", function () {
        console.log(Date.now());
    });
});
```

However, the event is being fired twice.
With `data-native-menu="true"` everything works alright.

I guess there is something to do with the popup of the selectmenu.

A demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/qL8SP/

Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? It runs only once for me :P

Comment: because `pageinit` is triggered twice, on main page and on opening select menu dialog, which is a page http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Spkm9/.

Comment: Okay. I've narrowed the problem. When you use `data-native-menu="false"` with a long options list (so a dialog is being generated) it's happening...
See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qL8SP/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding `change` event to any page, you have to bind it to `#page`. Whenever a page is initiated, it triggers `pageinit` and therefore it bind `change` event to `#selectbox` twice.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page",function () {
  console.log(Date.now()); // will trigger one time only
  $("#selectbox").on("change", function () {
    console.log(Date.now()); // will trigger when you select a value
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UeA9x/)**